# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkfilebrowser'

Tags: python, tkinter, steganography

I am trying a code to make a GUI but I keep on getting an error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkfilebrowser'.
There is a problem I get in the code that Unable to import 'tkfilebrowser'.

```
from PIL import Image
import tkinter
import tkinter.ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkfilebrowser import askopendirname, askopenfilename, asksaveasfilename

def gendat(data):#convert data into binary data

        newd=[]
        for i in data:
            newd.append(format(ord(i),'08b'))
        return newd

def modpix(pix,data):#To return the modified pixels

    datalist=gendat(data)
    lendata=len(datalist)
    imdata=iter(pix)

    for i in range(lendata):
        pix=[value for value in next(imdata)[:3] + next(imdata)[:3] + next(imdata)[:3]]

        for j in range(0,8):
            if (datalist[i][j]=='0') and (pix[j]%2!=0):
                if (pix[j]%2!=0):
                    pix[j]-=1
            elif (datalist[i][j]=='1') and (pix[j]%2==0):
                pix[j]-=1
#0 means keep reading; 1 means the message is over.
        if i==lendata-1:
            if pix[-1]%2==0:
                pix[-1]-=1
        else:
            if pix[-1]%2!=0:
                pix[-1]-=1

        pix=tuple(pix)
        yield pix[0:3]
        yield pix[3:6]
        yield pix[6:9]

def encode_enc(data):

    s2=tkinter.Tk()
    name=askopenfilename()
    image=Image.open(name,'r')
    global newimg
    newimg=image.copy()
```

Comment: did you `pip install tkfilebrowser`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hello according to the tkfilebrowser pypi describtion it is an alternative to a native tkinter module and need to be installed independently try

> pip install tkfilebrowser

for more info
https://pypi.org/project/tkfilebrowser/